# my lgl16c "lucky" is stuck optimizing apps after I changed the runtime

Tags: lg, art

my lgl16c was behaving very poorly to the point of which I went to the developer options and swapped the runtime from dalvik to art on android 4.4.2...and now it got stuck "optimizing app 1 of 1" after countless reboots...it's been stuck on this for days without anything changing, and there is no answer on google...is this a special case or what?

Comment: What OS version are you on? Lollipop? You changed from dalvik to art?

Comment: I did change from dalvik to art and I'm on version 4.4.2 Thank you for pointing that out BTW, I have made the appropriate edits.

Comment: How did you do the change?

Answer (score 0):

The Lucky does not have enough internal memory to use the Art runtime. You can remove the battery if it is stuck, and it should come to the conclusion that it has insufficient memory for the switch, and revert to Dalvik. Had the same issue last night. It will revert you to the default wallpaper as well, but other than that, it will be fine.